# C# fixed string length - compile time checking

Tags: c#, compile-time, string-length

I would like to declare a C# value type that only allows strings of a particular length. Said length should be validated at compile time. This is doable in Delphi as:

```
type
  TString10 = string[10];
```

and if I use said tyoe as:

```
var
  sTen : TString10;

sTen := '0123456789A';   //This generates a compile time error
```

Now as I understand it you cannot declare a string type in C# of a fixed length. Various solutions I have seen don't offer **compile time** checking for C#. As I am prepared to declare my own C# value type struct is this something I can achieve with `.Format()`?

All help and pointers greatly appreciated.

PS. I **really** would like to achieve compile time checking of string length assignments, so please no "Why are you....?"

Comment: Why are you so keen on compile time checking? Although you can do this in Delphi, it's a terribly outdated feature that has long been deprecated. Delphi short strings became obsolete around 15 years ago.

Comment: Mark gave you a good answer. Will you now please satisfy my curiosity and explain why?

Comment: @David: You are probably referring to ShortString which is different to Delphi's long string support which is what the string keyword represents.

Comment: @Jacek: I don't want to have to rely on unit testing to fix a clear bug which could be caught at compile time. Also say I had a type named TCountryCode and that was a 3 character string, and for some reason I decided to change it to a 2 character string, anywhere I had mistakenly used AUS instead of AU (where I had been sure I never user more than 2 characters) would be caught by the compiler.

I think that the type system in C# is severely lacking as compared to Delphi. The fact that you cannot alias types is a weakness IMHO

Comment: @TheEdge You clearly don't know Delphi very well. The short string is what I am referring to and in fact `string[10]` is a fixed length short string. Read all about it [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types#Short_Strings). Short string in Delphi is an anachronism that is never used in modern code. I can't understand why you hold it up as a paragon of virtue. It isn't.

Comment: @David: You are correct. However being able to strongly type my domain short string or not is what I am after. And that is virtuous IMO.

Comment: @TheEdge One thing you have not specified is what operations you want to perform on this new type.

Comment: All the usual operations I would be able to apply to a vanilla string type.

Comment: @David I can't see how this needs or can be verified in compile-time. Strings like "AU", "AUS" would probably end up being in a database, file or come from user-input, not in a compile-time known location. To me it looks like validation logic, that needs to work in runtime.

Comment: @Jacek I agree with you. Now it seems that TheEdge wants all the usual operations that are available for `string`. I believe that to be wishful thinking. It's not just the methods that the `string` class provides, it's the fact that everything in the framework assumes you are using the standard `string`. The expectations of TheEdge are unrealistic.

Comment: My previous comment was obviously addressed to TheEdge, my mistake.

Comment: It seems to me that everyone is happy to give up compile time checking. Instead you are relying on unit testing and runtime errors before you end up with a solid application. I also find it strange that people get defensive about this stuff when the language under question does not support a feature that has been around <qupte>for 20 years</quote>. I will investigate Spec# and Code Contracts to see if I can achieve what I need.

Answer (score 5):

Given that System.String has [this constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx):

```
public String(char[] value)
```

you could create your own value type like this:

```
public struct FixedLengthString
{
    private readonly string s;

    public FixedLengthString(char c1, char c2, char c3)
    {
        this.s = new string(new [] { c1, c2, c3 });
    }
}
```

This particular example would give you a string of exactly three characters, initialized like this:

```
var fls = new FixedLengthString('f', 'o', 'o');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/) you can constrain various things at compile time, including string length.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will investigate.

Answer (score 3):

I have a puzzle for you. Let's assume your `TString10` already exists in C#, and that a compile-time error should be raised when you assign strings that are too long:

```
string stringWithUnknownLength = "".PadLeft(new Random().Next(0, 100));

TString10 foo = stringWithUnknownLength;
```

Should a compile-time error be raised here? And if so, how would the compiler know *when* to raise it?

As you see, the possibilities of compile-time checking are limited. There's some things the compiler can easily verify, such as when you assign a specific string *constant* to a `TString10` variable. But there's a vast amount of cases where verification depends on possibly complex program logic, or on I/O, or on random numbers (like in the above example) — in all those cases, compile time checks are impossible.

---

I was originally going to suggest to you a combination of a wrapper class around `string`, combined with the static checking capabilities of [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992); however, that approach would suffer from the same fundamental problem. Anyway, for completeness' sake:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

class TString10
{
    private string value;

    …

    public static implicit operator TString10(string str)
    {
        Contract.Requires(str.Length <= 10);
        return new TString10 { value = str };
    }

    public static implicit operator string(TString10 str10)
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>().Length <= 10);
        return str10.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for CodeContracts that was thinking me too. Very clear and not code invasive solution, with compile time checking and without creating special types or whatever. May be pretty suitable for this question.

Comment: +1 for explaining the pointlessness of compile-time string length checking.

Comment: There are actually several languages (specifically those with _dependent types_) which enforce string/array bounds at compile time, forcing the programmer to either explicitly handle the out-of-bounds case or prove that it won't occur.  So, no, it's not impossible (although unlikely to ever be possible in C#).

Answer (score 1):

You may declare a readonly char array of a fixed length. The readonly need to avoid any further resize. However, that's not offers a direct string manipulation, but it's not too far from the way you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, there is no way to implement this in C# alone, because string literals are **always** `System.String`s and because the C# type system does is completely oblivious to array sizes.

Assuming you go with a custom value type (and yes, you have to declare 10 `char` fields, because `char[10]` would be stored on the heap),

```
struct String10
{
     char c0;
     char c1;
     ...
     char c9;

     public String10(string literal){...}
}
```

You could write a tool (as a post-compilation step) that goes through the IL and rejects every invocation of that `String10` constructor that doesn't have a valid (i.e. at most 10 characters) string **literal** as its parameter.

```
new String10("0123456789") //valid
new String10("0123456789A") //rejected
new String10(someString) //has to be rejected as well → undecidable ↔ halting problem
```

If you don't like having to write `new String10(...)`, you could define an implicit conversion from `System.String` to `String10` instead. Under the hoods, this would be a static method called by the C# compiler in your stead.

One library that allows you to look at IL is [mono.cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil%3aFAQ).

You will get a new data type, that is distinct from `System.String`. You can override the `ToString` method so that `String10` can be used in `String.Format` and friends, you could even define a widening (implicit) conversion to `System.String` so that you can use `String10` with APIs that expect a `System.String`.